# How to separate components with side effects?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm trying to create an agent based system in Haskell. For this I need to logically separate the agent and environment parts, for example to run using different test and real environments.

Both component types, agent and environment will have lots of stateful stuff going on, so I opted to use monad transformer stacks to build each one. I moved the component interface to a type class, which is implemented by the environment. Monads implementing this type class can be used to complete the whole transformer stack by plugging them into the agent transformer.

I created a working proof of concept, which is posted below.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleContexts, 
GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module MonadComponents where
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans


class Monad m => Environment m v | m -> v where
  envAction :: v -> m v

newtype AgentT r v m a = AgentT {unAgentT :: ReaderT r m a} 
    deriving (Monad, MonadTrans, MonadReader r)

runAgentT :: (Environment m v) => AgentT r v m a -> r -> m a
runAgentT = runReaderT . unAgentT

instance Environment IO Int where
  envAction x = do 
    putStrLn $ "action performed in IO environment " ++ (show x)
    return $ x * 2

agentAction :: (Environment m Int) => AgentT Int Int m Int
agentAction = do
  x <- ask
  lift $ envAction (x+10)

ioAction :: Int -> IO Int
ioAction = runAgentT agentAction
```

Although this kind of works, I see two problems with my code. First, AgentT itself cannot say that it only accepts Monads which are instances of Environment. That is only forced by the type signature of runAgentT. Second, the deeper a transformer stack gets, the complexer its resultant type after full evaluation can become. For example you need to collect and handle every result of StateT, WriterT, MaybeT, EitherT when they are in the stack at a single point at the end. So there is a location in the resulting program where the separation of components does not exist anymore.

I bet there are many different ways to do this. So, of which other ways can you think to separate side-effecting components via a well defined interface in Haskell?

Comment: I think you should elaborate on "many different ways"

Comment: Well, I thought about embedding monadic computations in arrows. As I want to have local state per component, I think I cannot use Kleisli composition. Instead I would have to evaluate the encapsulated monads locally and translate from a function call based interface (as above) to a message based interface between arrows.

Comment: The other thing I was thinking about, if type families can achieve a more convenient solution. Unfortunately I don't understand type families well enough yet to answer this myself.

Comment: Is the IO instance what's bothering you, felix?

Comment: No, I used the IO monad to keep the example simple. It could be any Monad(Trans) in a real implementation. I have added an explanation of my problems with the code to the question text.